# Why is the the last child of my navigation in my "ScrollSpy" function returning a value of undefined?

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I have a navigation menu we've all seen before, that is adding/removing a class based on the current scroll position.

Everything is working wonderfully so far, however the last "section" both in the content and in the navigation is returning a value of undefined, while the rest are behaving in the correct matter.

Here is a link to the stage site.

http://sites.atjayjo.com/cozy-two/frequently-asked-questions.php

And here is the JQuery I'm using:

```
var $sections = $('hgroup');
var $sectionsHead = $('hgroup h2');
var $navs = $('.faq-sidebar a');

var topsArray = $sections.map(function(){
    return $(this).position().top + 238;
}).get();

var len = topsArray.length;
var currentIndex = 0;

var getCurrent = function( top ) {
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (top > topsArray[i] && topsArray[i+1] && top < topsArray[i+1] ) {
            return i;
        }
    }
};

$(window).scroll(function(e){
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var checkIndex = getCurrent(scrollTop);;
    if (checkIndex !== currentIndex) {
        currentIndex = checkIndex;
        $navs.eq(currentIndex).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
        $('hgroup h2').removeClass('active');
        $sectionsHead.eq(currentIndex).addClass('active');
        // console.log(alert(currentIndex));
    }
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the

```
if (top > topsArray...)
```

line due to the evaluation of the expression.

Changing the line to:

```
if  ( top > topsArray[i] && (!topsArray[i+1] || top < topsArray[i+1]) )
```

and evaluating it as a ternary expression fixes this.